# how can I create connections among three linux-based machines?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, usb, ethernet

As far as hardware setup is concerned, there is an ethernet-based connection between my linux desktop (ubuntu 14.04) and the jetson tx1 (ubuntu 16.04). The raspberry pi 3 is connected to the jetson board via the USB-3.0-to-Ethernet adapter (AX11789).

Following the hardware setup, the software setup is done. At first, the `/etc/network/interface` file in my desktop is edited as follows:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 iface static
address 192.168.1.42
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.26
```

Then in my jetson,

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.26
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Because it seems correct that the jetson be configured as a gateway (router), the ip address of the jetson should be used as a gateway address in both the desktop and the pi board. So in the pi board,

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.102
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.26
```

After this, the `ping` requests between the desktop and the jetson as well as between the jetson and the pi work perfectly, but the ping request between the desktop and the pi board does not work, stating `Ping from 192.168.1.102: Destination host unreachable`.

Is there any critical information or step I am missing in this case? It may probably be due to the configuration with the Ethernet-to-usb adapter, but I'm not 100% certain about this.

Comment: You mention two Ethernet connections (from desktop & from raspi) to the jetson, but only demonstrate the configuration of one eth0.

Comment: If I were in your place, I might be able to get this working after a couple of hours of trying.  By which I mean, I sort-of understand this stuff, but not well enough to write a complete answer. But, based on my understanding, routers route between networks. If the desktop and the pi can’t communicate directly, they will need to be on different networks (e.g., 192.168.1 and 192.168.2), and the jetson will need to have two IP addresses (one on each network).  You’ll also need to *tell* the jetson that you want it to route between the two networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to understand what the "subnet mask" setting means: it defines which addresses are in the same Ethernet segment, and therefore *reachable without a gateway.*

For example, if your desktop's address is `192.168.1.42/255.255.255.0`, and you're asking it to reach the Rpi at `192.168.1.102`, it will see that both addresses are in the same subnet and *by definition* it will not use the gateway to reach it. (Instead it will immediately try to send ARP queries for that address.)

A router/gateway does not generally work that way. (A router sits *between* subnets, and the assumption is that every port on the router belongs to a different subnet.) So if you want two Ethernet ports to belong to the same subnet, it's the opposite of what you need.

---

To achieve a link like you described, you would need to set up the Jetson as a *bridge*. (A bridge only forwards based on the destination MAC address. Ethernet switches are just hardware-accelerated bridges.)

Configuration for that is different: you have to add a virtual "bridge" interface `br0`, then configure both Ethernet ports as its members:

```
iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.26/24
    bridge_ports eth0 usb0
```

(The individual "port" interfaces remain addressless.)

---

Alternatively, if you *want* the Jetson to act as a router, then both its interfaces will need to belong to different subnets (as G-Man as described in a comment). For example:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.26/24

iface usb0 inet static
    address 192.168.2.26/24
```

Since the Raspberry Pi is connected to the router's usb0, it would belong to the `192.168.2.*` network and use the corresponding gateway address.

Comment: so if I would like to use the jetson as a bridge, then should I remove the `gateway` in the `interface` files of both my desktop and the raspberry pi? and is it also okay that `eth0` and `usb0` remain addressless as the bridge automatically figures out?